# Google Sheet API inserting Multiple Rows Android

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to insert multiple Values in my Google Sheet Through API but it is giving me error, the error is listed below

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid values[1][0]: list_value {\n  values {\n    string_value: \"1041\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"28.4121001\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"77.0438644\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"2156-5091\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"ABCD\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"Sep 20 2017, 01:27 PM\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"NA\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"A1E85C43-B8C8-42F0-96EC-D1586FCBB2CF\"\n  }\n}\n",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid values[1][0]: list_value {\n  values {\n    string_value: \"1041\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"28.4121001\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"77.0438644\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"2156-5091\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"ABCD\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"Sep 20 2017, 01:27 PM\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"NA\"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: \"A1E85C43-B8C8-42F0-96EC-D1586FCBB2CF\"\n  }\n}\n",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Below is the code I am using to send the data to the sheet

```
      private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, AppendValuesResponse> {
        private com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets mService = null;
        private Exception mLastError = null;
        List<CustomerGeoData> mList;

        MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential, List<CustomerGeoData> mList) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Geo Tagger")
                    .build();

            this.mList = mList;
        }

        /**
         * Background task to call Google Sheets API.
         *
         * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
         */
        @Override
        protected AppendValuesResponse doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                return getDataFromApi();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mLastError = e;
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Sending the data to the Sheet
         * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLwONBo8SbjvVwEi_RCjzw8D8teHcdke-rkCEowq2bU/edit
         *
         * @return List of names and majors
         * @throws IOException
         */
        private AppendValuesResponse getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            String spreadsheetId = GeoTaggerConstants.CUSTOMER_GEO_DATA;
            String range = GeoTaggerConstants.CUSTOMER_GEO_DATA_SHEET_NAME + "!A1:H";

            Object[] additionalRows = new Object[mList.size()];
            Object[] cellValue;

            List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
                //Cell Values
                cellValue = new String[]{mList.get(i).getCustomer_Barcode(), mList.get(i).getLatitude(), mList.get(i).getLongitude(),
                        mList.get(i).getCustomer_No(), mList.get(i).getCustomer_Name(), mList.get(i).getLogged_At(),
                        mList.get(i).getLogged_By(), mList.get(i).getRow_ID()};

                //Additional Rows added here till the size of the list
                additionalRows[i] = Arrays.asList(cellValue);

                lastCustomerName = mList.get(i).getCustomer_Name();
            }
            values.add(Arrays.asList(additionalRows));    
            ValueRange body = new ValueRange().setValues(values);

            AppendValuesResponse result =
                    mService.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId, range, body)
                            .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                            .execute();


            return result;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Start Loading
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AppendValuesResponse output) {
            if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("No results returned.");
            } else {

                System.out.println("output  >>>  " + output);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            if (mLastError != null) {
                if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                    showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                            ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                    .getConnectionStatusCode());
                } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                    startActivityForResult(
                            ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The following error occurred:\n"
                            + mLastError.getCause());
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Request cancelled.");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what my `mList` looks like the data I am sending to the Sheet API

[image: Values sending looks like this]

Any help is appreciable, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Based from this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-spreadsheets-api/7fbHUmY3Tt4), you may encounter this error if you are specifying a range that is larger that the sheet (grid) currently is. If you use the `AppendCellsRequest` it should expand the size of the sheet automatically as you append. Suggested workaround is by using `Append` instead of `Update` method.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the kind reply, as I can see in the thread that the issue was because of the Range but my issue was because of the Invalid values, but all the data is correct and if I send a single data instead of multiple it is inserting correctly in the sheet.